# Let M/L, L/K be field extensions. Find a counterexample for each of the following.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let M/L, L/K be field extensions. Find a counterexample for each of
the following.

(a) If M/L and M/K are normal, then L/K normal.

(b) If L/K is normal, then M/L normal.

I saw similar but not the same questions in the forum. I think I should start with K = Q. However, I just cannot find counterexamples for these two questions.

Comment: First things first. Can you think of *any* non-normal field extension L/K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(a)$, take $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\omega)\supset \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\supset\Bbb Q$, where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity. Then $M/L$ is normal since it is quadratic, and $M/K$ is normal since it is the splitting field of $x^3-2$. However, $L/K$ is not normal because the irreducible polynomial $x^3-2$ has a root but does not split.

For $(b)$, take $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt 2)\supset\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)\supset\Bbb Q$. Then $L/K$ is quadratic, but $M/K$ is not normal since it is a real extension and thus does not contain the complex roots of $x^3-2$.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks!